# SQL Server 2008 TSQL loop through and calculate average time between start and end time

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to calculate the average time between start time and end time for a list of customers

I have two tables

```
Customer         Table
Id               Id
Name             CustId
                 Start time  (datetime)
                 End time    (datetime)
```

That contains the start and end times in minutes for a list of customers

How can I loop through all the customers and calculate the average time between start and end time?

So I end up with the result

```
Name                 Average time
John Doe             13 minutes
Jane Doe              9 minutes
Frank Paco            8 minutes
```

The start times and end times are in the format in the database of

2015-08-10 09:43:49.000

2015-08-10 09:47:35.000

Comment: Please provide sample data, as well as the desired results.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for data aggregation (AVG function for an avarage value over many rows). You want one result row per customer, so either you select from customer only and get the avarage time in a subquery or you join both tables and group by customer.

Option 1:

```
select 
  name,
  (
    select avg(datediff(minute, start_time, end_time))
    from times
    where cust_id = customer.id
  ) as avg_minutes
from customer;
```

Option 2:

```
select 
  c.name,
  avg(datediff(minute, t.start_time, t.end_time)) as avg_minutes
from customer c
left join times t on t.cust_id = c.id;
group by c.name;
```

Comment: I didn't see dnoeth's answer when answering myself. Of the three options I like my option 2 least. It is possible and often seen, but I don't like the idea of joining all the tables first and only then think about how to get out the desired results. A subquery as shown in my option 1 is easy to write and read, but only makes sense when you are only after one value from the other table. So dnoeth's approach is usually my favorite of all three.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop, simply aggregate:

```
select c.CustomerName, AvgTime
from Customer as c
join
 (
   select
      CustId,
      avg(datediff(minute, StartTime, EndTime) as AvgTime
   from tab
   group by CustId
 ) as t
on c.Id = t.CustId
```

If you want to include customers who didn't logon change to a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE(AvgTime, 0)`

Comment: There must be no quotes around `minute`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: fixed, my T-SQL is a bit rusty